# Fixing size in xaml file

Tags: c#, css, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm newbie with Wpf application i have this interface

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Alg="clr-namespace:AS.Views.DeformableModel"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Assergs.Windows.Controls;assembly=Assergs.Windows" x:Class="AS.Window1"
        Title="Window1"   
        >
    <Grid Margin="0,0,2,0">
        <Controls:RibbonPanel Header="Menu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,31.405" Width="213.388">
            <TreeView Width="210.449" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,-1.515"/>
        </Controls:RibbonPanel>
        <StatusBar Margin="0,472.595,0,0.972" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Label Content="Pret" Height="41.433" Width="36.737"/>
        </StatusBar>
        <StackPanel Margin="213.388,0,0,31.405">
            <Image Height="473.5" Source="image-interface2.jpg"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

i got as a result:
[image: result]

as you saw, there is many design error i need to know :

1. How can i display the image at the full stackpanel space ?
2. why the `RibbonPanel` controller disappeared?
3. How can i change my snippet to make all controller's size depending to the size of the window (image,treeview...)

Comment: Trying to copy your code. What is 'Assergs.Windows'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should to know about wpf's panels and layouts. The grid is an excellent panel and you can get almost any common layout. But for getting this you should works with columns and rows (not only with margins and vertical/horizontal orientations). The stack panel is not the best control for stretching an image: if the stackpanel's orientation is vertical the item'a height is the item's desired height, and if the orientation is horizontal, the item's width is the item's desired width, so, if you want to stretch the image you can group it inside a content control, or (if there is no more controls) do not group.

I suggest you to use a dockpanel, the dock panel alows you put the items in the locations top, right, bottom and left:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Alg="clr-namespace:AS.Views.DeformableModel"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Assergs.Windows.Controls;assembly=Assergs.Windows" x:Class="AS.Window1"
        Title="Window1"   
        >
    <DockPanel Margin="0,0,2,0">
        <Controls:RibbonPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" Header="Menu" Width="213.388">
            <TreeView /> <!--The tree view will be vertican and horizontally stretch-->
        </Controls:RibbonPanel>
        <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="41.433">               
            <Label Content="Pret"  Width="36.737"/>
        </StatusBar>
        <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="image-interface2.jpg"/> <!--The last item take all aviable space-->
    </DockPanel>

</Window>
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

Read about Layout Containers.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140613/WPF-Tutorial-Layout-Panels-Containers-Layout-Trans

In your case you may use dock panel as parent panel.
Use Grid or Border instead panels. (I have not tested this code)

```
<DockPanel Margin="0,0,2,0">
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <Label Content="Pret" Height="41.433"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="213">
        <TreeView Width="210.449" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="image-interface2.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```